# How to convert a csv to xml in logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I was trying to access my csv file in a blob. And trying to convert the same into an XML.

I can't find any link to read the csv file data. Can anyone please help me out with some light? I am very new in logic apps.

Comment: Done by creating an Azure function and called the same from Logic app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add your integration account and add the schema you want like this [article](https://seroter.com/2016/09/09/trying-out-standard-and-enterprise-templates-in-azure-logic-apps/).

Then click `Integration account` in your logic app and relate with the Intergation account you created before.

Then add `Flat File Decoding` to pick the schema and use `Transform XML` to convert csv to xml.

[image]

For more details you could refer to this [article](http://blogs.recneps.net/post/Using-Azure-Logic-Apps-to-Import-CSV-to-SQL-Server).